# Excel vba - HttpRequest GET

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, http-request

Estou tentando fazer um GET em VBA no Excel, e encontrei vários exemplos, segue abaixo o que estou usando:

```
Sub http()
    Dim MyRequest As Object

    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    MyRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", False

    MyRequest.Send

    MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText

End Sub
```

Em todos os exemplos que testei, mostra o seguinte erro quando executa o `MyRequest.Send`:

"Erro em tempo de execução '-2147012889 (80072ee7)':
O Nome ou o endereço do servidor não pode ser resolvido"

Já inclui a referência `Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1` no meu projeto.

O que pode estar acontecendo ou faltando?

**EDIT**
Tentei também alterar:

```
MyRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", True
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

"Erro em tempo de execução '-2147483638 (8000000a)':
Os dados necessários para concluir esta operação ainda não estão disponíveis"

OBS: A rede aqui na empresa é protegida por firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulei aqui com seu mesmo código e funcionou corretamente.
Inclusive quando alterado o valor do parâmetro para `true` exibiu o mesmo erro.

Para mim, o erro "O Nome ou o endereço do servidor não pode ser resolvido" acontece se digito propositalmente um nome inválido de URL. Com isso, presumi o seguinte:

> **1º** Dá certo ao buscar com outros endereços?
>
> > Se sim, então seu DNS não está conseguindo encontrar especificamente alguns endereços. Troque o DNS.
>
> **2º** Se o seu computador ou rede estão protegidos por uma firewall ou um proxy, verifique se o excel tem permissão de acesso à Web.

Comment: Não da já tentei vários sites diferentes e da o mesmo erro. Então deve ser o que você disse, pois estou tentando fazer isso no banco onde eu trabalho e aqui é cheio disso... O que não entendo é que consigo acessar esses sites, mas pelo excel da esse erro.

Comment: Se o problema for a segunda opção, teria alguma solução?

Comment: @Thiago Adicionei uma entrada manual no firewall e na verdade, o erro retornado foi "Uma conexão com o servidor não pôde ser estabelecida" com isso, também devemos descartar a 2º opção. Vou fazer um outro teste com o DNS e já te retorno.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/66857)

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo não fornece resposta à pergunta porquê?

Answer (score -2):

Aqui também deu o mesmo erro.
Mas, quando coloquei a URL com http**s** em vez de http, o código funcionou bem!

```
MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.google.com", False
```